# Set breakpoint to event in google chrome debugger

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Sorry if this question was mentioned. I have web page with bunch of javascript files. One of it has function that sets value to some input on HTML file. Is it possible to see via debugger which javascript function invokes changing of value of the input HTML element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the `input` tag that you are willing to observe and select **Break On** and then **Attribute Modifications**. Your scripts will stop if they try to modify the input value.

[image]